# Kile missing "Settings" dialog after update to kubuntu 12.10

Tags: kubuntu, kile

After update to Kubuntu 12.10, I can no longer access configuration options in Kile from Settings->Configure kile (or whatever the menu entry was for configuration).

In fact, "Settings" menu has only five entries: "Define current document as master document", "System check", "Show side bar", "Show message bar", and "Toolbars shown."

I did a fresh install of Kubuntu 12.10 on one of my other computers, and same problem. I even tried adding the (unsupported) ppa:kile/stable, but the problem persists. Any ideas?

I need to access settings to set PDF Latex to use "modern" compilation mode, so that I can use synctex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try removing the user specific file for Kile.  I had the same problem after I messed with the toolbars.

```
~$ rm ~/.kde/share/apps/kile/kileui.rc
```

These guys had the [had the same problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12366826).  They suggest the folder ~/.kde4 where on my system 12.10 (64) it was in ~/.kde.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'll try that on Monday when I get back to my office.

Comment: OK, I can confirm that ajrichards' suggestion worked. Thanks! accepting the answer....

Comment: Did not work for me with Ubuntu 12.10 64bit - but Erik's approach does the trick for me

Comment: I had the same problem... and it worked, but now whenever I change the ui the same thing happens. How do I change the ui now ?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 it was in ~/.kde/share/apps/kile/katepart and the filename was katepartui.rc

Answer (score 8):

My installation of Kile lost the entries in the settings dialogue as soon as I changed one item in any of the toolbars. My solution for this might help you out as well.

It appeared I could avoid this by adding the button "*Configure Kile*" to a toolbar.

This approach retains your personalised toolbars.

<sup>My sytem: Kile 2.1.0 / KDE 4.9.4 @ Kubuntu 12.04</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Another way of getting system settings back is by resetting your toolbar: right click the toolbar, select "Configure Toolbars...", and then click the "Defaults" button on the lower left.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution for this...

```
vim ~/.kde/share/config/kilerc
```

there I edited the MainWindow configuration, 
just search the word MainWindow using

`/KileMainWindow`

and edited the keyword value named `MenuBar`.
I founded it configured like this:

```
MenuBar=Disabled
```

after that I switched to `able`.

Saved the file, re-launch Kile and worked perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.